# Can I Create a Higher Order Function With Funciton Parameters from Different Classes?

Tags: c++, class, oop, higher-order-functions

So, I have this project where I have to recreate the most basic of MySQL functions, operating over a database of Songs (which are represented in a class).

I have created another class which is my Interface (user interface). I use it for getting commands, recognizing parameters, and so on. I want to create a higher order function, which takes several parameters. Some of them will be primitive data types, but there will also be two functions as parameters.

Now, one of the functions comes from the same class (Interface), but the other function comes from the Songs class. The problem is that I can't figure out how to reference the function within that class?

I was thinking of making the class static because you can only create one database of type Songs anyways. That would most probably give me the possibility of using the Songs:: reference, but I'm not sure that this is going to fix my problem.

Besides a solution, I am also asking for a more detail explanation on higher order functions in C++, I can't seem to find a good resource. And all of the resources that I've found don't say anything about higher order functions that take parameters of functions from other classes.

```
class Song
{
public:
    string getName() const;
    string getSinger() const;
    unsigned int getLength();
    unsigned short getYear() const;

private:
    char singer[51];
    char name[51];
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned short year;
};
```

And then in Interface:

```
bool isEqual(string, string);
template<typename T>
bool isSmaller(T firstElement, T secondElement);
template<typename T>
bool isGreater(T firstElement, T secondElement);
```

I want to create a higher order function which checks the value of the comparator function. However, one of the values which the comparator has to take has to come from a Songs object. In other words, I have to also pass one of the 4 getters, depending on the situation.

Comment: Perhaps a sample of your existing code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [member function pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions). And here's an simple example of a generic higher order function:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void Call(T* obj,  Func T::* memFuncPtr)
{
 (obj->*memFuncPtr)();
}
```

`Call` accepts a generic object pointer and a pointer to a member function of that object's class and simply calls that function. For example,

```
class A
{
public:
 void foo()
 {
   cout<<"A::foo() called\n";
 }

 void bar()
 {
   cout<<"A::bar() called\n";
 }
};

int main()
{
 A a;
 Call(&a, &A::foo);
 return 0;
}
```

In addition to member function pointers, the [Boost.FunctionTypes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/introduction.html) library gives you a handle on the functions signature. These techniques should be a good starting point.

Note that if you didn't want to use templates, you can write out a non-generic definition, by specifying both the object type and the member function signature.

```
void CallA(A* obj,  void (A::*)() memFuncPtrOfA)
{
 (obj->*memFuncPtr)();
}
```

Since both `A::foo` and `A::bar` satisfy the function signature in `CallA`'s second argument, you can call them both:

```
A a;
CallA(&a, &A::foo);
CallA(&a, &A::bar);
```

Comment: By the way, your first example with the template gives me an error on the obj->(*memFuncPtr)(); line - Unqialified ID before ( token

Comment: One last thing lol...I think that you've also made a mistake on the class-specific (CallA) version. Instead of:
(A* obj,  void (A::*)() memFuncPtrOfA)
the argument list should be:
(A* obj,  void (A::*memFuncPtrOfA)())
  as well as the call in the function itself

Comment: No problem at all. HTH.